# how to convert following program into generic program in java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Convert the following into generic program in Java.
It is array 1 Dimensional program. I am having issue in converting it in generic program. Please help me..!

```
public class Array1D {
    protected int AS;
    protected Object[] elements;

    public Array1D(int initialCapacity) {
        if (initialCapacity < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("initialCapacity must be >= 1");
        }
        elements = new Object[initialCapacity];
        AS = initialCapacity;
    }

    public Array1D() {
        elements = null;
        AS = 0;
    }

    public void create(int initialCapacity) {
        if (initialCapacity < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("initialCapacity must be >= 1");
        }
        elements = new Object[initialCapacity];
        AS = initialCapacity;
    }

    void checkIndex(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= AS) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index = " + index + "Size = " + AS);
        }
    }

    public boolean put(int index, Object theElement) {
        checkIndex(index);
        elements[index] = theElement;
        return true;
    }

    public Object get(int index) {
        checkIndex(index);
        return elements[index];
    }

    public Object remove(int index) {
        checkIndex(index);
        Object ob = elements[index];
        elements[index] = null;
        return ob;
    }

    public int indexOf(Object theElement) {
        for (int i = 0; i < AS; i++) {
            if (elements[i] == theElement) //if(elements[i].equals(theElement))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int length() {
        return AS;
    }

    public Object[] changeLength(int newLength) {
        Object newArray[] = new Object[newLength];
        System.arraycopy(elements, 0, newArray, 0, AS);
        elements = newArray;
        AS = newLength;
        return newArray;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < AS; i++) {
            if (elements[i] == null) {
                s.append("__, ");
            } else {
                s.append(elements[i].toString() + ", ");
            }
        }
        if (AS > 0) {
            s.delete(s.length() - 2, s.length());
        }
        s.append("]");
        return new String(s);
    }

}
```

End of array class.
This is its runner class.
I'm passing 8 elements in an array.

```
public class Runner {
    static Array1D a = new Array1D(8);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Length of array is:  " + a.length());
        System.out.println("Array: " + a.toString());

        System.out.println();
        a.put(0, (Character) 'A');
        System.out.println("'A' Stored at 0, Array: " + a.toString());
        a.put(2, (Character) 'B');
        System.out.println("'B' Stored at 2, Array: " + a.toString());
        a.put(5, (Character) 'C');
        System.out.println("'C' Stored at 3, Array: " + a.toString());

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Output for get(0) is:  " + a.get(0));
        System.out.println("Output for get(2) is:  " + a.get(2));
        System.out.println("Output for get(6) is:  " + a.get(6));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Index of a: " + a.indexOf((Character) 'B'));
        System.out.println("Index of c: " + a.indexOf((Character) 'C'));
        System.out.println("Index of q: " + a.indexOf((Character) 'q'));

        System.out.println();
        a.put(0, (Character) 'A');
        System.out.println("'A' Stored at 0, Array: " + a.toString());
        a.put(2, (Character) 'B');
        System.out.println("'B' Stored at 2, Array: " + a.toString());
        a.put(5, (Character) 'C');
        System.out.println("'C' Stored at 3, Array: " + a.toString());

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(a.remove(0) + " removed from 0, Array: " + a.toString());
        System.out.println(a.remove(1) + " removed from 1, Array: " + a.toString());

        a.changeLength(10);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Length of array is:  " + a.length());
        System.out.println("Array: " + a.toString());

        Character ch = 65;
        System.out.println();
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < a.length(); ctr++) {
            a.put(ctr, ch);
            System.out.println("'" + ch + "'" + " Stored at " + ctr + ", Array: " + a.toString());
            ch++;
        }
    }

}
```

End of runner class.

Comment: Step one, format the code so it can be read.

Comment: Step two, look on http://learnertobeginner.blogspot.com/2011/06/basics-of-java-generics.html, and do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics aren't hard to learn (only hard to master). But here you go:

```
public class Array1D<E> {
    protected int AS;
    protected Object[] elements;

    public Array1D( int initialCapacity){ 
        if(initialCapacity < 1)  
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("initialCapacity must be >= 1");
        elements = new Object[initialCapacity];
        AS = initialCapacity;
    }

    public Array1D(){
        elements = null;
        AS = 0;
    }

    public void create(int initialCapacity){ 
        if(initialCapacity < 1)  
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("initialCapacity must be >= 1");
        elements = new Object[initialCapacity];
        AS = initialCapacity;
    }

    void checkIndex(int index){
        if(index < 0 || index>=AS )
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException ("index = "+ index + "Size = "+ AS);
    }

    public boolean put( int index, E theElement ){
        checkIndex(index);
        elements[index] = theElement;
        return true;
    }

    public E get( int index ){
        checkIndex(index);
        return (E)elements[index];
    }

    public E remove( int index ){
        checkIndex(index);
        E ob = (E)elements[index];
        elements[index] = null;
        return ob;
    }

    public int indexOf(E theElement){
        for(int i=0;i<AS; i++)
            if(elements[i]==theElement)
            //if(elements[i].equals(theElement))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }

    public int length(){
        return AS;
    }

    public Object[] changeLength(int newLength){
        Object newArray[]= new Object[newLength];
        System.arraycopy(elements, 0, newArray, 0, AS); 
        elements=newArray;
        AS=newLength;
        return newArray;
    }

    public String toString(){ 
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < AS; i++) 
            if(elements[i] ==null) 
                s.append("__, "); 
            else s.append(elements[i].toString() + ", "); 
        if(AS > 0) 
            s.delete(s.length() -2, s.length()); 
        s.append("]");
        return new String(s); 
    }
}
```

Note that you can't allocate a generic array. The only way is to allocate an `Object` array and cast it to `E` whenever needed.

You can then create an `Array1D` of characters using `Array1D<Character> a = new Array1D<>();` and it should force the data structure to only hold characters.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy, to do the quick and dirty.  Just put all of the methods and class members into another class that has a "public static void main" method in it.   Then make sure all members and methods that you just copied in are static.   Then, in that main method, just call other methods in the same class in whatever order and with whatever values you want.

Comment: after putting all methods and class members in another class that has  "public static void main" method in it means main/runner class then what will come in Array 1D class?

Comment: Just make it an inner class?